# How to capture a devices information through a WCF Service and Authenticate using it?

Tags: wcf, authentication, device, mac-address

Is there anyway to capture a devices information and create an Authentication method against the information that is gained. It would work something along the lines of when a Mobile Device connects to the WCF Service through a Native Application it checks the devices information which would be already stored on a DB (SQL) such as a MAC Address and then will confirm in a Database that the Device in question is authorized to access the WCF Service through the Application and will continue to load the App as normal.

Comment: Yes it is! Why on MAC-address? What is the reason to not trust your clients?

Comment: @Jocke Yes what is? It would be part of an Authentication method. Its not about trust but would link together with their username and password to provide more security.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the device identification on the http headers of the request and then validate it on your Global.asax using the Application_BeginRequest method.

Something like this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ValidateDevice(Context.Request.Headers["X-Device-ID"]))
    {
        Context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Context.Response.StatusDescription = "Invalid device";
        Context.Response.End();
    }
}
```

This is one of many solutions to your scenario.